# Missing shutdown file on OS X

Tags: macos, file, find, shutdown, missing-data

I have recently moved the shutdown file in /sbin/ directory and I lost the content of the shutdown executable.

I can't shutdown the computer because of it.

Can someone tell me where can I get this file without reinstalling the OS? Any advice for recovering\reinstalling this executable?
or can someone upload this file for me.
or copy paste the content of the file on pastebin.com

I have Yosemite 10.10
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you need to reinstall the os (unless you trust someone to give you that file from the same system, and better the same model machine)

Reinstalling do not clear your personal data, it will just overwrite alla system files (adding the missing `/sbin/shutdown`)

If you have a recent mac you have the recovery partition. Have a read here:
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314

Basically you just need to power your Mac holding down <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>